# How can I pass arrays and objects through props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass from father component to a child component arrays and objects.
What is the best way to pass those via props?

Thank you

Comment: Arrays and objects are like any other value (strings, numbers, booleans, functions). You pass them all the same way

Comment: `<Component someProp={someObject} />` same with arrays

Answer (score 0):

Just like you would pass strings to a component, you just need to specify to the jsx that you are going to use js with {}.

It would be like this:

```
render() {
    const array = [1,2,3];
    cosnt obj = {
        a: 1,
        b: 2
    };

    return <SomeComponent array={array} obj={obj} />   
}
```